# Calculating error in a series

Tags: convergence-divergence

I need to determine if the following series cponverges. Which I believe I have done correctly, but then I must determine how many terms must be summed to guarantee an error no greater than $\frac {1}{10}$. This second part I am having some trouble with.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{0.001}}$. Clearly this series is alternating so I used the criteria for alternating series test.

First looking at the limit criteria as $a_n$ must go to $0$ for a alternating series to converge.

$lim \frac{1}{n^{0.001}} = 0$.

Then comparing the $n+1$ to $n$ we see that $\frac {1}{(n+1)^{0.001}}$ is clearly less than $\frac {1}{n^{0.001}}$. So this series must converge by the alternating series test.

Now looking at the second part I began to calculate the sum of the series,

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{0.001}} = 1- 0.993+ 0.9989- 0.9986$. Looking at this sum how can I possibly get it to be no greater than $\frac {1}{10}$

Comment: Have you learn about maximum error for an alternating series? By the way, you are going to need a lot of terms here. This series converges like a snail

Comment: @imranfat hahaha I know this is my problem

Comment: You essentially need to solve an equation involving the expression of the series and that $0.1$. Do you know what it is?

Comment: @imranfat no I am not quite sure

Comment: could you help me out with this?

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/EstimatingSeries.aspx read bottom page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may use the fact that $\frac1{n^{0.001}}$ converges monotonically to $0$, thus,

$$\left|\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{0.001}}\right|<\frac1{k^{0.001}}$$

And just choose the proper value of $k$ (it's going to have to be big, as the series converges super slowly).

If one is interested in evaluating the series faster, applying an [Euler transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation), I get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{0.001}}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac1{2^{j+1}}\sum_{n=0}^j\binom jn\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{0.001}}$$

Estimating with an upper bound of $p$, I get

$$\begin{array}{c|c}p&\sum_{j=0}^p\frac1{2^{j+1}}\sum_{n=0}^j\binom jn\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{0.001}}\\\hline
1&0.500\ 173\ 226\ 752\ 386\ 869\ 519\\
2&0.500\ 209\ 202\ 375\ 383\ 508\ 224\\
3&0.500\ 219\ 829\ 114\ 274\ 006\ 399\\
10&0.500\ 225\ 746\ 925\ 048\ 072\ 352\\
20&0.500\ 225\ 760\ 827\ 952\ 674\ 479\\
30&0.500\ 225\ 760\ 834\ 158\ 697\ 626\\
40&0.500\ 225\ 760\ 834\ 162\ 478\ 372\end{array}$$

which is the correct value out $16$ places.

The exact value is given by

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{0.001}}=\eta(0.001)\\=0.500\ 225\ 760\ 834\ 162\ 481\ 008\ 261\ 982\ 830\ 758\ 637\ 859\ 937\ 556\ 152\ 849$$

which should agree conceptually with the linear approximation of the eta function around $x=0$:

$$\eta(x)\approx\left(\frac12\ln\frac\pi2\right)x+\frac12$$

$$\eta(0)\approx0.500225791$$

Comment: is that enough to show that the series converges?

Comment: or should I still use my AST

Comment: @hburt Convergence?  You already showed convergence with AST, so I thought you wanted to calculate the sum out yourself with accuracy of $0.1$.

Comment: yes sorry my question was a bit confusing. Yes I do want to calculate the sum with accuracy of 0.1

Comment: @hburt Yes.  I mean, if you want to drop being correct to pick up "how to evaluate this much faster", than I can do that.  Particularly, the solution is $\approx0.5$, for the record.

Comment: how did you calculate that? and how many terms must be summed to guarenetee that?

Comment: @hburt I bumped it to$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{0.001}}\approx\lim_{x\to0^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^x}=\eta(0)=0.5$$

Comment: so how many terms is that? and is that alright to do to change it like that? it seems like that is the only reasonable thing to do

Comment: Be patient for a few moments.  I'm trying to give you an answer XD

Comment: okay thanks so much

Comment: @hburt Phew!  So many numbers!  :D

Comment: haha that was a lot of work, thanks. So how many terms was that?

Comment: @hburt Uh.. I actually cheated and used a thing called a "series accelerator", which let's me approximate a series many folds faster.  (i.e., I gave up on the original series.  If you are wondering, the accelerator here used $p+1$ terms of the original series.  In other words, approximation with only 11 terms)

Comment: okay and is that covered in your answer?

Comment: @hburt It is under "Euler transform", which is what I used.

Comment: thanks so much for your clear and precise answer

Comment: @hburt No problem :-)

Comment: @hburt I updated btw, in case you needed the first 30 or so digits.  :P

Comment: thanks again for your time