# Terrible equation $(x+x^{\ln x})^{10}=2^{10}$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

$$(x+x^{\ln x})^{10}=2^{10}$$ I tried to take the logarithm of both sides. To apply 10th root, but didn't get too far. Please help!

Edit: I have the following result which tells me that it has only one solution. $$x^{\ln x}=2-x$$  we take logarithm on both sides$$\ln^2{x}=\ln{(2-x)}$$ $\ln^2{x}$ is strictly increasing function (for $x>0$) and this function $\ln(2-x)$ is strictly decreasing (because is a composition of a strictly increasing one with a decreasing one). So we have only one solution $x=1$. What is wrong here?

Comment: $x=1$ is a solution.

Comment: It has another solution besides $1$ as well..

Comment: You got as far as $|x+x^{\ln x}| = 2$, right? And $x$ must be positive, otherwise $\ln x$ is undefined; so $x+x^{\ln x} = 2$.

Comment: There is another solution, slightly greater than $1/2$.

Comment: @TonyK Yess. That far I went

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After taking the 10th root on both sides, we obtain:
$$|x+x^{\ln{x}}|=2$$
Note that since $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, we can deduce that:
$$x+x^{\ln{x}}=2$$
Now, this equation has a solution which is obvious, at $x=1$. However, there is another solution to this equation.

I do not think there is a closed form solution in terms of elementary functions for $x$. Therefore, we must use a numerical method. I will use the [Newton-Raphson Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

The process is as follows:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

We choose an initial starting point $x_0=0.2$, a reasonable estimate of the solution.

We use the functions:

$f(x)=x+x^{\ln x}-2$

And find its derivative:

$f'(x)=2\ln{x} \cdot x^{\ln{x}-1}+1$

To obtain the iteration:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n+{x_n}^{\ln{x_n}}-2}{2\ln{x_n} \cdot {x_n}^{\ln{x_n}-1}+1}$$

Doing this gives the solution:

\begin{array}{c|c}n&x_n\\\hline0&0.2\\1&0.253997\\2&0.322907\\3&0.402142\\4&0.476180\\5&0.523933\\6&0.539434\\7&0.540775\\8&0.540784\\9&0.540784\end{array}

As the iterations $n \to \infty$, $x_n \to x$, the solution to the equation. Therefore:

$$x \approx 0.54078414712$$

You can implement this method to a spreadsheet, or by a more sophisticated software such as MATLAB.

Comment: Personally, I like to show the process of the iteration, but good answer anyways :D

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I am actually adding this process to my answer now.

Comment: Oh.  :D  (and just for the record, I like tables like this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112441/calculating-error-in-a-series/2112453#2112453)

Comment: Nice job.  +2  :D

Comment: @projectilemotion with the method you used, how do you know which solution your sequence aproximates? I presume this method could be used to aproximate also $x=1$. What starting point do you get?

Comment: For $x=1$, you can select a starting point $x_0\geq 1$ and you will obtain a solution which converges to $x=1$. For example, with $x_0=1.5$ it takes $n=5$ iterations to get $x$ correct to 10 decimal places.

Comment: Ok. So I should take a starting point as close as I can to the solution. 
Are there any requirements for the function? (i.e. monotony?)

And how did you know in the first place that the function has two solutions. I edited the question with a proof that seems to me correct which shows that it has just one solution.

Comment: @projectilemotion I've graphed these two functions $\ln (x^{\ln x})$ and $(\ln x)^2$ and they seem completely the same on $(0,\infty)$

Comment: @projectilemotion Yes, the functions you've graphed are indeed different. But mine are. https://www.desmos.com/calculator. My claim is that $\ln (x^{\ln x})=\ln x \ln x = (\ln x)^2$ isn't this the property of the logarithm?

Comment: I apologize, I forgot about the other $\ln $.

Comment: I think I see the mistake in your proof. $\ln^2(x)$ is strictly increasing at $x\geq \color{red}{1}$, since $\ln(x)<0$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and $\ln(x)\geq 0$ for $x\in [1,\infty)$.